# IOS: add an object in a specific position of a NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, nsmutablearray

In my project I want to add an object in a specific position of a NSMutableArray, example:

```
if(index ==1) {
// I want add object at position 1 of NSMutableArray
}

if(index == 2) {
// I want add object at position 2 of NSMutableArray
}
...
if(index == 15) {
// I want add object at position 15 of NSMutableArray
}
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

use `[array insertObject:object atIndex:index];`

Comment: Please note that `index` must not be greater that the count of elements in the array.

Comment: but in this way, if I add an object atindex:0 and after I add an object atIndex:3, it gives me an error because I haven't add yet abject at position 1 e 2....How can I solve?

Comment: @blackguardian - This is an assumption based on the fact that I don't see your complete code, but maybe you might want to use a dictionary instead of an array?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a C array for this.

```
id objects[15];

objects[index] = yourObject;
```